# Get parameters from the JS value key

Tags: javascript

I face the problem and I hope they will help me here with advice.

There is an array of objects. (urlParams.categories)

I want to output using the extension operator (...) not all of these objects in their entirety, but the specific value of these objects by key (id). i.e.: 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on

I can do this using "for in" or "forEach", but I'm want to know if it can be done with (...)

I tried to do it like this:

```
let urlParams = {
  'categories': [
    { id: '1', name: 'Test' },
    { id: '2', name: 'Test' },
    { id: '3', name: 'Test' },
    { id: '4', name: 'Test' }
  ]
}

console.log(urlParams.categories)
console.log(...urlParams.categories.id)
```

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: That requires `urlParams.categories.id` to be an array, but the array is `urlParams.categories`

Comment: `urlParams.categories.map(cat => cat.id)`

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+get+property+values+from+array+of+object) of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19590865/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the `categories` to get the `id`:

```js
const urlParams = {
  'categories': [
    { id: '1', name: 'Test' },
    { id: '2', name: 'Test' },
    { id: '3', name: 'Test' },
    { id: '4', name: 'Test' }
  ]
}

console.log(urlParams.categories.map(({id}) => id))
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can do this using "for in" or "forEach", **but I'm want to know if it
> can be done with (...)**

No, the `...` called [`Spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). So from the definition on specs, everything you can do like this:

```
const categories = [...urlParams.categories];
```

to get an array of categories. After that, you have to use `.map` or something can loop such as `for, forEach, reduce, etc..` to get exactly `id` of each category.

```js
let urlParams = {
  'categories': [
    { id: '1', name: 'Test' },
    { id: '2', name: 'Test' },
    { id: '3', name: 'Test' },
    { id: '4', name: 'Test' }
  ]
};

const categories = [...urlParams.categories];
const result = categories.map(r => +r.id);
console.log(result);
```